# php foreach($a as $b) in jquery-tmpl

Tags: php, foreach, jquery-templates

Help! I have no idea about this jquery-tmpl stuff... just kinda making it up as I go. I got down `{{if something}} {{/if}}` But I have no idea how to do this foreach loop.

How can I write `foreach($a as $b){}`

EDIT:

Since the title didn't help out at all, I should have been spoon-feedingly clear for everyone: How can I take a php foreach loop such as foreach($a as $b){Do Something Here } and write it in x-jquery-tmpl. I need a simple example using $a and $b because I have no idea how to do this and the google results I have read make 0 sense to me otherwise I wouldn't have posted here.

And a sincere thank you to those who posted answers below, I'm trying to get through them but still tough for me.

Comment: RTFM? http://api.jquery.com/template-tag-each/

Comment: Are you kidding me man? First link out of [google](https://www.google.com/search?hl=en&q=jquery+tmpl+foreach), returned [this link](http://api.jquery.com/template-tag-each/). Do your homework next time.

Comment: This question is not constructive!

Comment: no, i am not joking. I have never used this before, so I have no idea how to read the answers off google. My developer just dumped some stuff on me that doesn't work, now I gotta figure it out. anyway, i got {{each( index, value ) collection}} content {{/each}} but I have no idea what to do with the examples as they don't match what I have in front of me.

Comment: Deconstructing your question: the first paragraph is just your background. We can't answer that. The second paragraph is a question, "How can I write foreach($a as $b){}". You should be able to answer this question by reading the documentation.

Comment: Spoon feeding? Seriously? If all the people here can't get your question, then it means your question is vague. Not that people are stupid.

Answer (score 4):

First link out of [google](https://www.google.com/search?hl=en&q=jquery+tmpl+foreach), returned [this link](http://api.jquery.com/template-tag-each/).

```
<li>
    Title: ${Name}.
    {{each Languages}}
        ${$index + 1}: <em>${$value}. </em>
    {{/each}}
</li>
```

Do your homework next time.

Answer (score 1):

From the [docs](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.tmpl/):

> If data is an array, the template is rendered once for each data item in the array. If data is an object, or if the data parameter is missing or null, a single template item is rendered.

So you should be able to just write

```
var template = "<div>${a}</div>";
var data = [ { a: "hello" }, { a: "world" } ];
$.tmpl(template, data);
```

And each item in data will get rendered in a div.

Answer (score 1):

```
//Iliterating Object in Jquery
$.each(obj, function (key, value) {
    alert(key + ': ' + value);
});
//Iliterating Array in Jquery
//To do it in jQuery, you can do it like this:

$.each(arr, function (index, value) {
    alert(index + ': ' + value);
});
```

hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

The `jQuery.tmpl()` method is designed for chaining with `.appendTo`, `.prependTo`, `.insertAfter` or `.insertBefore` like this:

```
$.tmpl( "<li>${Name}</li>", { "Name" : "Johnny Bravo" }).appendTo( "#targetDiv" );
```

You can read more about on: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.tmpl/

and for the php foreach:

```
<?php
$arr = array(1, 2, 3, 4);
foreach ($arr as &$value) {
    $value = $value * 2;
}
// $arr is now array(2, 4, 6, 8)
unset($value); // break the reference with the last element
?>
```

also with a great documentation http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php

Answer (score 0):

read the link http://api.jquery.com/template-tag-each/

Example:

```
        {{each Languages}}
            ${$index + 1}: <em>${$value}. </em>
        {{/each}}
```

Comment: please read the article thoroughly,if you find trouble understanding, ask me.